# Какое отношение между классами будет?

Tags: java

Композиция, это один класс является частью другого, например двигатель не может существовать без машины, так как класс машина создает себе экземпляр двигателя самостоятельно например в конструкторе.

```
public class Car{ 
    private Engine engine;
    public Car(){ 
       engine = new Engine();
    }
}
```

Агрегация это когда один класс содержит другой класс, например двигатель передается в конструктор автомобиля и уже может существовать без автомобиля, даже если он будет уничтожен.

```
public class Car{
    private Engine engine;
    public Car(Engine engine){
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}
```

То тогда вопрос, если я создаю абстрактный класс Engine и два наследника EclctricMotor  и FuelEngine и добавляю его поле в класс Car, а в конструкторе создаю экземпляр его наследника, скажем FuelEngine(по сути композиция) и создаю сеттер на двигатель(что уже по сути агрегация), то какое отношение будет иметь класс автомобиль по отношению к классу двигатель? Ведь он получается содержит и композицию и агрегацию ‍♂️

```
public class Car{
    private Engine engine;
    public Car(){
        engine = new Engine();
    }
    public setEngine(Engine engine){
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}
```

Что то вроде этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. На диаграмме отобразил интерфейс engine. Но в данном случае это роли не играет

Comment: Один клас частью другого, это уже про вложенные классы?

Comment: @RomanC нет, это не про вложенные классы. Вложенные классы, это когда один класс определен внутри другого. Например:
public class A{
    public class B{
    }
}

В данном примере, класс В вложенный(inner class)

Вот статья например про них 
https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.12.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это одно и тоже, просто взгляд снутри и снаружи. Композиция это собрание как бы независимых деталей в одно целое. И целое агрегированные из деталей. По сути это поля объекта и как они проинициализированы и используются объекту ровно, это важно только пользователю

Answer (score 1):

"Композиция", "агрегация" - бессмысленные ярлыки.

Автомобиль содержит двигатель - вот их отношение.